# incorrect sorting and/or searching an array populated through an external file

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, filestream

So the problem is that I'm taking a sample file for input asking for a user account number. Now, the output is:

```
What is the filename of account numbers? sample.txt
What is the account number you are looking for? 5552012
-858993460
4520125
5658845
7895122
8451277
1302850
8080152
4562555
5552012
5050552
7825877
1250255
1005231
6545231
3852085
7576651
7881200
4581002
The account number you were looking for is: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The numbers that are output underneath: "What is the account number?" are due to a 'for' loop for debugging purposes. The problem with the output as well is that the top number (-858993460) isn't a number that exists inside the sample.txt file. The number that should be there is 5658845 instead. I'm guessing the negative number is the smallest int possible though.

This part is the code that I'm working with. It seems like the bubble sort algorithm isn't working quite right. But, as instructed, we are to follow the book example which I did exactly. I've checked the algorithm functions several times and found no errors but I could be wrong with my assessment. This issue leads to a larger issue which prevents the correct account number from being found in the sorted array, which in it's current state returns 1, which isn't a number that exists.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//prototypes
void sortAcctNums(int accounts[], int arraySize);
bool findAcctNum(int accounts[], int numElems, int accountNumSearched);


//main part of the program. This is where all the magic happens
int main(){
    string fileName;
    int accountNumSearched, count = 0;
    const int arraySize = 18;
    int accounts[arraySize];
    int location;

    fstream inputFile(fileName, ios::in);
    cout << "What is the filename of account numbers? ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (inputFile.is_open()){//makes sure the file is able to be read, if not then requests user to try again
        cout << "What is the account number you are looking for? ";
        cin >> accountNumSearched;
        while (inputFile >> accounts[count]){
            count++;//populates the array
        }
        inputFile.close();//closes the file stream

        sortAcctNums(accounts, arraySize);//sorts the account numbers
        location = findAcctNum(accounts, arraySize, accountNumSearched);//assigns the value of the fundAcctNum function to location
        if (location == -1){
            cout << "The account number could not be found" << endl;
            exit;
        }
        else
            cout << "The account number you were looking for is: " << location << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error opening file. Please try again. " << endl;

    return 0;
}

//this function sorts the account numbers with a bubble sort algorithm
void sortAcctNums(int accounts[], int arraySize){

    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do{
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < (arraySize - 1); i++){
            if (accounts[i] > accounts[arraySize + 1]){
                temp = accounts[i];
                accounts[i] = accounts[arraySize + 1];
                accounts[arraySize + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
    //this loop is only for testing purposes and should be removed during final build
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        cout << accounts[i] << endl;

    }
}

//This function searches the sorted array for the specified account number with a Binary sort algorithm
bool findAcctNum(int accounts[], int numElems, int accountNumSearched){

    int first = 0,
        last = numElems - 1,
        middle,
        position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last){
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (accounts[middle] == accountNumSearched){
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (accounts[middle] > accountNumSearched)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
    }
    return position;
}//end search
```

Comment: In case you didn't notice, you're bubble sort isn't decrementing the bubble-to point with each iteration (and it should). there is no sense in comparing against what is already bubbled to the right side because it already beat out everything else in the array. And `sortAcctNums(accounts, arraySize)` should use `count` as the second parameter, as that is how any entries you actually *read*.

Comment: I understand what you say somewhat. The use of count is a better option than arraySize. But I don't really understand when you say that the bubble isn't decrementing the bubble to point with each iteration. Do you mean that I'm continually scaling and sorting to the right?

Comment: [**See a working `bubblesort()`**](http://ideone.com/XisXKL) Note particularly how the top end (where already sorted items reside) is continuously *reduced*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Okay, now I understand the bubblesort. But there is an entirely new problem once the correct bubblesort algorithm is implemented. There are only 3 elements of the array output in the for loop code. Plus, the returned value isn't ever anything but 1, but that's the sortAcctNums function.

Comment: If you adjusted the algorithm to match the one I linked, that simply means `arraySize` was decremented with each pass until a 3-length sequence remained, and it was already sorted so the algorithm terminated. If you want to dump the entire sequence post-bubble-sort, do it *after* the function invoke (and again use `count` for the top-end, as that is the number of elements you actually read).

Comment: @WhozCraig So I tested it again this morning and found that, while not changing your linked bubble sort, the function works! I changed the location of the for loop that prints out the numbers for testing purposes in ascending order to be underneath ' cout << "The account [...] for it: " << location << endl;'. Placing the for loop here actually orders everything correctly but there's the same issue as before that persists and that is the return of a wrong element, which always prints 1. I'm assuming for true after the return of the  findAcctNum() function runs.

Comment: @WhozCraig I found the solution, full correct code detailed below in my own answer.

Comment: +1 to your answer, and props for working it out yourself. I don't feel like I did some give-away by linking that bubblesort for you. The algorithm is well-documented and there are probably *millions* of implementations already on the web. But I knew once you had *it* and your implementation side by side you could see what works and why, and then concentrate more on what appears to be the real purpose of this assignment; the binary-search. Grats for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct program is:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//prototypes
void sortAcctNums(int accounts[], size_t count);
int findAcctNum(int accounts[], int numElems, int accountNumSearched);


//main part of the program. This is where all the magic happens
int main(){
    string fileName;
    int accountNumSearched, count = 0;
    const int arraySize = 18;
    int accounts[arraySize];
    int location;

    fstream inputFile(fileName, ios::in);
    cout << "What is the filename of account numbers? ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (inputFile.is_open()){//makes sure the file is able to be read, if not then requests user to try again
        cout << "What is the account number you are looking for? ";
        cin >> accountNumSearched;
        while (inputFile >> accounts[count]){
            count++;//populates the array
        }
        inputFile.close();//closes the file stream

        sortAcctNums(accounts, sizeof(accounts)/sizeof(*accounts));//sorts the account numbers
        location = findAcctNum(accounts, count, accountNumSearched);//assigns the value of the fundAcctNum function to location



        if (location == -1){
            cout << "The account number could not be found" << endl;
            exit;
        }
        else
            cout << "The account number you were looking for is: " << accounts[location] << endl
    }
    else
        cout << "Error opening file. Please try again. " << endl;

    return 0;
}

//this function sorts the account numbers with a bubble sort algorithm
void sortAcctNums(int accounts[], size_t count){

    bool swap = true;
    int temp;

    while (count-- && swap){
        swap = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i){
            if (accounts[i] > accounts[i + 1]){
                std::iter_swap(accounts + i, accounts + i + 1);
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

//This function searches the sorted array for the specified account number with a Binary search algorithm
int findAcctNum(int accounts[], int numElems, int accountNumSearched){

    int first = 0,
        last = numElems - 1,
        middle,
        position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last){
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (accounts[middle] == accountNumSearched){
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (accounts[middle] > accountNumSearched)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
    }
    return position;
}//end search
```

Comment: +1. In case you're wondering why the bubblesort uses the whole `while (count-- ...)`approach as opposed to a `for (i=0;i<(count-1)...` approach. I'm a firm believer that unless you seriously know what you're doing array subscripts should be *unsigned* (like `size_t`). Now think about what madness ensues if you opened an *empty* file to sort. What would`(count-1)` become when `count` as an unsigned value is *zero* (0) ? Yeah, not good. Underflow. Ouch. Hope that made sense.

Comment: That does make sense. And thanks! Although should you always use unsigned variables in array subscripts?

Comment: If you're writing both sides of the code (caller and callee) I *strongly* advise it. The time you use negative subscripts is so rare it almost isn't worth even mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Your bubble sort is not at all correct. You have:

```
do{
    swap = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < (arraySize - 1); i++){
        if (accounts[i] > accounts[arraySize + 1]){
            temp = accounts[i];
            accounts[i] = accounts[arraySize + 1];
            accounts[arraySize + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
} while (swap);
```

That's not a bubble sort. You'll need nested `for` loops for a bubble sort. Go back to your example and make sure you're implementing it exactly. A typical bubble sort would look similar to this this:

```
swap = true;
for (int i = 0; i < (arraySize - 1) && swap; ++i)
{
    swap = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < (arraySize - i - 1); ++j)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1])
        {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you're getting that bogus number in your array is because you're comparing the current item (`accounts[i]`) with `accounts[arraySize+1]`. In this case, you're comparing against `accounts[20]`. Since there are only 18 items in the array, you're comparing against some random value that's stored in memory off the end of the array. The negative number is not the smallest possible int.

Comment: Um. *that* isn't bubble sort either. Bubble sort bubbles a value to a continually descending end-point using adjacent element comparison, restarting after decrementing the end-point and outright stopping when no swaps happened in any single pass. Your inner loop should be continually getting shorter on the *top* side with each pass. For some reason you have the *bottom* shrinking *up*, not the top shrinking *down*, and that is wrong. As written this won't sort correctly. A simple list of {3,2,1} with your algorithm finishes as {2,1,3}, which is *not* sorted.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are correct in your assessment. I've tested this and the result is not correct. The values seem to follow the same pattern you described to a degree.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're right. I confused my selection and bubble sorts. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < (arraySize - 1); i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < arraySize - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1]) {
            int swap   = array[j];
            array[j]   = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Try that and see whether you're still getting bad results.